# How to evaluate variable values to select a column in R

Tags: r

I have a list of youtube videos that I want to evaluate what the audience retention is at 30 seconds. The videos vary in length and view counts. When I query the YT Analytics API, audience retention data is returned in percentages. I cleaned up the data, and an example of it is shown below

I have a dataframe with video info like this

```
videoData <- data.frame(videos = c("Video1", "Video2", "Video3"),
                        Sec_30 = c(0.01, 0.02, 0.3))
```

and a dataframe as follows

```
myDF <- data.frame(videos = c("Video1", "Video2", "Video3"),
                   totalViews = c(542,4353,6345),
                   `0.01` = c(500, 4000, 6000),
                   `0.02` = c(400, 3000, 5000),
                   `0.03` = c(300, 2000, 4000))
```

In the real dataframe, the columns go from `0.01` to `1.00` with 150 videos, and the videoData dataframe has 150 rows with the video and what percentage to look at in the next df, each number representing the 30-sec percentage of the video. So if a video is 120 seconds long, then 30 seconds is 25% of the video, so I want to get the video views in the `0.25` column. Using the example dataframes, I'd want to do something like

```
myDF <- left_join(myDF, videoData, by="videos")
videoData$ViewsAt30Seconds <- myDF[,eval(videoData$Sec_30)]
```

Which doesn't work, but I want to evaluate the value in the `Sec_30` column to know which column to pull the value from, so I'd hope for a column that returns something like

```
myDF$ViewsAt30Seconds
>  500
> 3000
> 4000
```

Comment: As long as `Sec_30` is a `character` class column, then drop the `eval()` and `myDF[, videoData$Sec_30]` should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use row/column indexing to extract the values in a vectorized way

```
myDF$ViewsAt30Seconds <- myDF[-(1:2)][cbind(match(myDF$videos, videoData$videos), 
          match(names(myDF)[-(1:2)], videoData$Sec_30))]
```

-ouptut

```
myDF
  videos totalViews 0.01 0.02 0.03 ViewsAt30Seconds
1 Video1        542  500  400  300              500
2 Video2       4353 4000 3000 2000             3000
3 Video3       6345 6000 5000 4000             4000
```

#### data

```
myDF <- data.frame(videos = c("Video1", "Video2", "Video3"),
                   totalViews = c(542,4353,6345),
                   `0.01` = c(500, 4000, 6000),
                   `0.02` = c(400, 3000, 5000),
                   `0.03` = c(300, 2000, 4000), check.names = FALSE)
videoData <- data.frame(videos = c("Video1", "Video2", "Video3"),
                        Sec_30 = c(0.01, 0.02, 0.03))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same result by pivoting your dataframe so that your colum names become values, and then joining on those values.

```
myDF %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(videos, totalViews), names_to = 'Sec_30', names_ptypes = list(Sec_30 = numeric())) %>%
  inner_join(videoData)
```

```
videos totalViews Sec_30 value
  <fct>       <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 Video1        542   0.01   500
2 Video2       4353   0.02  3000
```